# Eureka SelectableSection get value from selectedRows

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I have problem with `selectedRows()` in `SelectableSection`.

Using Xcode 8, Swift 3, Eureka 2.0.0-beta.1.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    let branch_section = SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>>("Branches", selectionType: .multipleSelection)
    branch_section.tag = "branch_section"
    for branch in branchList {
        let branchStr = String(branch.id)
        branch_section <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(branch.name){ row in
            row.title = branch.name
            row.selectableValue = branchStr
            row.value = nil
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func saveFilter(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let branch_section = self.form.sectionBy(tag: "branch_section") as? SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>>        
    invoiceParams["branches"] = branch_section!.selectedRows().map({$0.value!})
}
```

now i have problem with this line `invoiceParams["branches"] = branch_section!.selectedRows().map({$0.value!})`

> map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type
>   'AnyObject?'

What is problem here? This worked with previous versions on swift 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see from [SelectableSection.swift](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/e3b51dc3834267515246be5486c37d88941b998c/Source/Core/SelectableSection.swift) `selectedRows` returns an array of `SelectableRow` items:

```
public func selectedRows() -> [SelectableRow] {
    return filter({ (row: BaseRow) -> Bool in
        row is SelectableRow && row.baseValue != nil
    }).map({ $0 as! SelectableRow})
}
```

So the `map` function also returns an array.

Your `invoiceParams` seems to be a dictionary that expects `AnyObject?` as value.

You can try to change the declaration of `invoiceParams` to something like `var invoiceParams: [String: [Any]] = [:]`.

Since I don't know `Eureka` this is just a guess. But I hope it still helps a little.

Comment: Actually, declaration needs to be: `var invoiceParams: [String: Any] = [:]` but your answer is correct.. thanks..